# Implementing a critical section in CUDA

Tags: cuda, synchronization, locking, critical-section

I'm trying to implement a *critical section* in CUDA using atomic instructions, but I ran into some trouble. I have created the test program to show the problem:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void k_testLocking(unsigned int* locks, int n) {
    int id = threadIdx.x % n;
    while (atomicExch(&(locks[id]), 1u) != 0u) {} //lock
    //critical section would go here
    atomicExch(&(locks[id]),0u); //unlock
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //initialize the locks array on the GPU to (0...0)
    unsigned int* locks;
    unsigned int zeros[10]; for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {zeros[i] = 0u;}
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&locks, sizeof(unsigned int)*10));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(locks, zeros, sizeof(unsigned int)*10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    //Run the kernel:
    k_testLocking<<<dim3(1), dim3(256)>>>(locks, 10);

    //Check the error messages:
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    cutilSafeCall(cudaFree(locks));
    if (cudaSuccess != error) {
        printf("error 1: CUDA ERROR (%d) {%s}\n", error, cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code, unfortunately, hard freezes my machine for several seconds and finally exits, printing out the message:

```
fcudaSafeCall() Runtime API error in file <XXX.cu>, line XXX : the launch timed out and was terminated.
```

which means that one of those while loops is not returning, but it seems like this should work.

As a reminder `atomicExch(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val)` atomically sets the value of the memory location stored in address to `val` and returns the `old` value. So the idea behind my locking mechanism is that it is initially `0u`, so one thread should get past the `while` loop and all other threads should wait on the `while` loop since they will read `locks[id]` as `1u`. Then when the thread is done with the *critical section*, it resets the lock to `0u` so another thread can enter.

What am I missing?

By the way, I am compiling with:

```
nvcc -arch sm_11 -Ipath/to/cuda/C/common/inc XXX.cu
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, and this is yet-another-one-of-the-cuda-paradigm-pains.

As any good cuda programmer knows (notice that I did not remember this which makes me a bad cuda programmer, I think) all threads in a warp must execute the same code. The code I wrote would work perfectly if not for this fact. As it is, however, there are likely to be two threads in the same warp accessing the same lock. If one of them acquires the lock, it just forgets about executing the loop, but it cannot continue past the loop until all other threads in its warp have completed the loop. Unfortunately the other thread will never complete because it is waiting for the first one to unlock.

Here is a kernel that will do the trick without error:

```
__global__ void k_testLocking(unsigned int* locks, int n) {
    int id = threadIdx.x % n;
    bool leaveLoop = false;
    while (!leaveLoop) {
        if (atomicExch(&(locks[id]), 1u) == 0u) {
            //critical section
            leaveLoop = true;
            atomicExch(&(locks[id]),0u);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This has been discussed several times on the NVIDIA forums.  I think the conclusion is that this only works if you can ensure that the number of blocks is less than or equal to the number of multiprocessors.  If not, it can lead to deadlock.  In other words, try to find another way of implementing your algorithm that doesn't require critical sections.

Comment: I did not understand your explanation at first, thinking that warp divergence actually allowed threads in the same warp to do different things. For future readers in my same situation, I would like to add that threads in the same warp may execute different instructions, but while some threads execute one branch, the *others are disabled until that branch is completed*.

Comment: Why can't I replace `atomicExch(&(locks[id]),0u);` with `locks[id] = 0u;`? (Tried it, didn't work)

Comment: @John Could you explain your solution?

Comment: @Eric Can you provide any explanation (links?) why the above code leads to a deadlock in the case you have mentioned?

Answer (score 13):

The poster has already found an answer to his own issue. Nevertheless, in the code below, I'm providing a general framework to implement a *critical section* in CUDA. More in detail, the code performs a block counting, but it is easily modifyiable to host other operations to be performed in a *critical section*. Below, I'm also reporting some explanation of the code, with some, "typical" mistakes in the implementation of critical sections in CUDA.

**THE CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#define NUMBLOCKS  512
#define NUMTHREADS 512 * 2

/***************/
/* LOCK STRUCT */
/***************/
struct Lock {

    int *d_state;

    // --- Constructor
    Lock(void) {
        int h_state = 0;                                        // --- Host side lock state initializer
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_state, sizeof(int)));  // --- Allocate device side lock state
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_state, &h_state, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); // --- Initialize device side lock state
    }

    // --- Destructor
    __host__ __device__ ~Lock(void) { 
#if !defined(__CUDACC__)
        gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_state)); 
#else

#endif  
    }

    // --- Lock function
    __device__ void lock(void) { while (atomicCAS(d_state, 0, 1) != 0); }

    // --- Unlock function
    __device__ void unlock(void) { atomicExch(d_state, 0); }
};

/*************************************/
/* BLOCK COUNTER KERNEL WITHOUT LOCK */
/*************************************/
__global__ void blockCountingKernelNoLock(int *numBlocks) {

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) { numBlocks[0] = numBlocks[0] + 1; }
}

/**********************************/
/* BLOCK COUNTER KERNEL WITH LOCK */
/**********************************/
__global__ void blockCountingKernelLock(Lock lock, int *numBlocks) {

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        lock.lock();
        numBlocks[0] = numBlocks[0] + 1;
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

/****************************************/
/* BLOCK COUNTER KERNEL WITH WRONG LOCK */
/****************************************/
__global__ void blockCountingKernelDeadlock(Lock lock, int *numBlocks) {

    lock.lock();
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) { numBlocks[0] = numBlocks[0] + 1; }
    lock.unlock();
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(){

    int h_counting, *d_counting;
    Lock lock;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_counting, sizeof(int)));

    // --- Unlocked case
    h_counting = 0;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_counting, &h_counting, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    blockCountingKernelNoLock << <NUMBLOCKS, NUMTHREADS >> >(d_counting);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&h_counting, d_counting, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("Counting in the unlocked case: %i\n", h_counting);

    // --- Locked case
    h_counting = 0;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_counting, &h_counting, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    blockCountingKernelLock << <NUMBLOCKS, NUMTHREADS >> >(lock, d_counting);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&h_counting, d_counting, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("Counting in the locked case: %i\n", h_counting);

    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_counting));
}
```

**CODE EXPLANATION**

Critical sections are sequences of operations that must be executed sequentially by the CUDA threads.

Suppose to construct a kernel which has the task of computing the number of thread blocks of a thread grid. One possible idea is to let each thread in each block having `threadIdx.x == 0` increase a global counter. To prevent race conditions, all the increases must occur sequentially, so they must be incorporated in a critical section.

The above code has two kernel functions: `blockCountingKernelNoLock` and `blockCountingKernelLock`. The former does not use a critical section to increase the counter and, as one can see, returns wrong results. The latter encapsulates the counter increase within a critical section and so produces correct results. But how does the critical section work?

The critical section is governed by a global state `d_state`. Initially, the state is `0`. Furthermore, two `__device__` methods, `lock` and `unlock`, can change this state. The `lock` and `unlock` methods can be invoked only by a single thread within each block and, in particular, by the thread having local thread index `threadIdx.x == 0`.

Randomly during the execution, one of the threads having local thread index `threadIdx.x == 0` and global thread index, say, `t` will be the first invoking the `lock` method. In particular, it will launch `atomicCAS(d_state, 0, 1)`. Since initially `d_state == 0`, then `d_state` will be updated to `1`, `atomicCAS` will return `0` and the thread will exit the `lock` function, passing to the update instruction. In the meanwhile such a thread performs the mentioned operations, all the other threads of all the other blocks having `threadIdx.x == 0` will execute the `lock` method. They will however find a value of `d_state` equal to `1`, so that `atomicCAS(d_state, 0, 1)` will perform no update and will return `1`, so leaving these threads running the while loop. After that thread `t` accomplishes the update, then it executes the `unlock` function, namely `atomicExch(d_state, 0)`, thus restoring `d_state` to `0`. At this point, randomly, another of the threads with `threadIdx.x == 0` will lock again the state.

The above code contains also a third kernel function, namely `blockCountingKernelDeadlock`. However, this is another wrong implementation of the critical section, leading to deadlocks. Indeed, we recall that warps operate in lockstep and they synchronize after every instruction. So, when we execute `blockCountingKernelDeadlock`, there is the possibility that one of the threads in a warp, say a thread with local thread index `t≠0`, will lock the state. Under this circumstance, the other threads in the same warp of `t`, including that with `threadIdx.x == 0`, will execute the same while loop statement as thread `t`, being the execution of threads in the same warp performed in lockstep. Accordingly, all the threads will wait for someone to unlock the state, but no other thread will be able to do so, and the code will be stuck in a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

by the way u have to remember that global memory writes and ! reads aren't completed where u write them in the code ... so for this to be practice you need to add a global memfence ie __threadfence()

Answer (score 0):

@Vitality. I am unable to comment under your response, so I write an answer here.

I have ran your code and it seems like both `lock` and `no lock` version will output an **incorrect answer**. I think the reason behind this is that you **do not change the value in the numBlocks atomically**.
Supposing a thread `t1` gets the lock and executes the code `numBlocks[0] = numBlocks[0] + 1;`, and then it frees the lock. Now another thread `t2` gets the lock and reads the value in `numBlocks`. Because the operation performed by `t1` isn't atomic, the value read by `t2` may be an old value. So we will get an incorrect value.

We can correct it by replacing the code `numBlocks[0] = numBlocks[0] + 1` with `atomicAdd(numBlocks, 1)`. Thank you for your general code and clear explanation.