# CUDA: Atomic operations on unsigned chars

Tags: cuda, atomic

I'm a CUDA beginner. I have a pixel buffer of unsigned chars in global memory that can and is updated by any and all threads. To avoid weirdness in the pixel values, therefore, I want to perform an atomicExch when a thread attempts to update one. But the programming guide says that this function only works on 32- or 64-bit words, whereas I just want to atomically exchange one 8-bit byte. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the update?  if you want to flip a number to 0 or 1, yuou could use atomicAnd/Or

Comment: I'm incrementing the value of a pixel depending on how many objects "reside" in that pixel. So if my increment is 50 for each object, then one object will result in a pixel with RGBA of (50,50,50,50), whereas two objects will have RGBA (100,100,100,100), etc., up to (255,255,255,255) max. This enables me to vary the intensity of a pixel depending on how many objects are "inside" that pixel.

Comment: I found a hack, BTW. Since a uchar4 takes up the same space as an int (though not guaranteed, it works on my architecture), I just take the address of the uchar4, cast it as an (int*), then use the integer version of atomicExch. I would still be interested whether you could do atomics on only a single byte, tho...

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem recently. In theory, atomic operations / optimistic retries are supposed to be faster than locks/mutexes, so the "hack" solutions that use atomic operations on other data types seem better to me than using critical sections.

Here are some implementations based on the threads for [how to implement atomicMin for char](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/493190/cuda-programming-and-performance/atomicmin-on-char-is-there-a-way-to-compare-char-to-in-to-use-atomicmin-/post/3531960/) and [atomicAdd for short](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/495219/cuda-programming-and-performance/how-to-use-atomiccas-to-implement-atomicadd-short-trouble-adapting-programming-guide-example/1).

I've tested all of these, and my tests seem to show that they work fine so far.

**Version 1 of atomicAdd for char**

```
__device__ static inline char atomicAdd(char* address, char val) {
    // offset, in bytes, of the char* address within the 32-bit address of the space that overlaps it
    size_t long_address_modulo = (size_t) address & 3;
    // the 32-bit address that overlaps the same memory
    auto* base_address = (unsigned int*) ((char*) address - long_address_modulo);
    // A 0x3210 selector in __byte_perm will simply select all four bytes in the first argument in the same order.
    // The "4" signifies the position where the first byte of the second argument will end up in the output.
    unsigned int selectors[] = {0x3214, 0x3240, 0x3410, 0x4210};
    // for selecting bytes within a 32-bit chunk that correspond to the char* address (relative to base_address)
    unsigned int selector = selectors[long_address_modulo];
    unsigned int long_old, long_assumed, long_val, replacement;

    long_old = *base_address;

    do {
        long_assumed = long_old;
        // replace bits in long_old that pertain to the char address with those from val
        long_val = __byte_perm(long_old, 0, long_address_modulo) + val;
        replacement = __byte_perm(long_old, long_val, selector);
        long_old = atomicCAS(base_address, long_assumed, replacement);
    } while (long_old != long_assumed);
    return __byte_perm(long_old, 0, long_address_modulo);
}
```

**atomicCAS for char**

```
__device__ static inline char atomicCAS(char* address, char expected, char desired) {
    size_t long_address_modulo = (size_t) address & 3;
    auto* base_address = (unsigned int*) ((char*) address - long_address_modulo);
    unsigned int selectors[] = {0x3214, 0x3240, 0x3410, 0x4210};

    unsigned int sel = selectors[long_address_modulo];
    unsigned int long_old, long_assumed, long_val, replacement;
    char old;

    long_val = (unsigned int) desired;
    long_old = *base_address;
    do {
        long_assumed = long_old;
        replacement = __byte_perm(long_old, long_val, sel);
        long_old = atomicCAS(base_address, long_assumed, replacement);
        old = (char) ((long_old >> (long_address_modulo * 8)) & 0x000000ff);
    } while (expected == old && long_assumed != long_old);

    return old;
}
```

**Version 2 of atomicAdd for char (uses bit shifts instead of __byte_perm and has to handle overflow as a result)**

```
__device__ static inline char atomicAdd2(char* address, char val) {
    size_t long_address_modulo = (size_t) address & 3;
    auto* base_address = (unsigned int*) ((char*) address - long_address_modulo);
    unsigned int long_val = (unsigned int) val << (8 * long_address_modulo);
    unsigned int long_old = atomicAdd(base_address, long_val);

    if (long_address_modulo == 3) {
        // the first 8 bits of long_val represent the char value,
        // hence the first 8 bits of long_old represent its previous value.
        return (char) (long_old >> 24);
    } else {
        // bits that represent the char value within long_val
        unsigned int mask = 0x000000ff << (8 * long_address_modulo);
        unsigned int masked_old = long_old & mask;
        // isolate the bits that represent the char value within long_old, add the long_val to that,
        // then re-isolate by excluding bits that represent the char value
        unsigned int overflow = (masked_old + long_val) & ~mask;
        if (overflow) {
            atomicSub(base_address, overflow);
        }
        return (char) (masked_old >> 8 * long_address_modulo);
    }
}
```

For atomicMin, please check [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/493190/cuda-programming-and-performance/atomicmin-on-char-is-there-a-way-to-compare-char-to-in-to-use-atomicmin-/post/3531960/).

Answer (score 1):

You might implement a critical section using a mutex variable.
So something like

```
get_the_lock
exch_data
release
```

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=185809

[Implementing a critical section in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021019/how-to-implement-a-critical-section-in-cuda)

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329536/115751) has a bug in its implementation of `atomicCAS()`.  This version works for me:

```
__device__
static inline
uint8_t
atomicCAS( uint8_t * const address,
           uint8_t   const compare,
           uint8_t   const value )
{
    // Determine where in a byte-aligned 32-bit range our address of 8 bits occurs.
    uint8_t    const     longAddressModulo = reinterpret_cast< size_t >( address ) & 0x3;
    // Determine the base address of the byte-aligned 32-bit range that contains our address of 8 bits.
    uint32_t * const     baseAddress       = reinterpret_cast< uint32_t * >( address - longAddressModulo );
    uint32_t   constexpr byteSelection[]   = { 0x3214, 0x3240, 0x3410, 0x4210 }; // The byte position we work on is '4'.
    uint32_t   const     byteSelector      = byteSelection[ longAddressModulo ];
    uint32_t   const     longCompare       = compare;
    uint32_t   const     longValue         = value;
    uint32_t             longOldValue      = * baseAddress;
    uint32_t             longAssumed;
    uint8_t              oldValue;

    do
    {
        // Select bytes from the old value and new value to construct a 32-bit value to use.
        uint32_t const replacement = __byte_perm( longOldValue, longValue,   byteSelector );
        uint32_t const comparison  = __byte_perm( longOldValue, longCompare, byteSelector );

        longAssumed  = longOldValue;
        // Use 32-bit atomicCAS() to try and set the 8-bits we care about.
        longOldValue = ::atomicCAS( baseAddress, comparison, replacement );
        // Grab the 8-bit portion we care about from the old value at address.
        oldValue     = ( longOldValue >> ( 8 * longAddressModulo )) & 0xFF;
    }
    while ( compare == oldValue and longAssumed != longOldValue ); // Repeat until other three 8-bit values stabilize.

    return oldValue;
}
```