# CUDA, mutex and atomicCAS()

Tags: c++, cuda, mutex, atomic

Recently I started to develop on CUDA and faced with the problem with atomicCAS().
To do some manipulations with memory in device code I have to create a mutex, so that only one thread could work with memory in critical section of code.

The device code below runs on 1 block and several threads.

```
__global__ void cudaKernelGenerateRandomGraph(..., int* mutex)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    ...

    do 
    {
        atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1 + i);
    }
    while (*mutex != i + 1);

    //critical section
    //do some manipulations with objects in device memory

    *mutex = 0;

    ...
}
```

When first thread executes

```
atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1 + i);
```

mutex is 1. After that first thread changes its status from Active to Inactive, and line

```
*mutex = 0;
```

**is not executed**. Other threads stays forever in loop. I have tried many variants of this cycle like while(){};, do{}while();, with temp variable = *mutex inside loop, even variant with if(){} and goto. But result is the same.

The host part of code:

```
...
int verticlesCount = 5;
int *mutex;
cudaMalloc((void **)&mutex, sizeof(int));
cudaMemset(mutex, 0, sizeof(int));
cudaKernelGenerateRandomGraph<<<1, verticlesCount>>>(..., mutex);
```

I use Visual Studio 2012 with CUDA 5.5.

The device is NVidia GeForce GT 240 with compute capability 1.2.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPD:**
After some time working on my diploma project this spring, I found a solution for critical section on cuda.
This is a combination of lock-free and mutex mechanisms.
Here is working code. Used it to impelment atomic dynamic-resizable array.

```
// *mutex should be 0 before calling this function
__global__ void kernelFunction(..., unsigned long long* mutex) 
{
    bool isSet = false; 
    do 
    {
        if (isSet = atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1) == 0) 
        {
            // critical section goes here
        }
        if (isSet) 
        {
            mutex = 0;
        }
    } 
    while (!isSet);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2021019/442006

Comment: I have to replace `mutex = 0;` with `atomicExch(mutex, 0);` in your solution to get it work, but why?

Comment: @whenov changing `mutex = 0;` to `atomicExch(mutex, 0);` has no effect due to the `if (isSet)` branch. Only one thread which acquires the mutex sets `isSet` to `true` and then sets `mutex` to `0`. No need to `atomicExch` operation because the code guarantees that the `mutex = 0` will be executed only by one thread at a time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The loop in question

```
do 
{
    atomicCAS(mutex, 0, 1 + i);
}
while (*mutex != i + 1);
```

would work fine *if it were running on the host (CPU) side*; once thread 0 sets `*mutex` to 1, the other threads would wait exactly until thread 0 sets `*mutex` back to 0.

However, GPU threads are not as independent as their CPU counterparts. GPU threads are grouped into groups of 32, commonly referred to as *warps*. **Threads in the same warp will execute instructions in complete lock-step**. If a control statement such as `if` or `while` causes some of the 32 threads to diverge from the rest, **the remaining threads will wait** (i.e. sleeps) **for the divergent threads to finish.** [1]

Going back to the loop in question, thread 0 becomes inactive because threads 1, 2, ..., 31 are still stuck in the `while` loop. So thread 0 never reaches the line `*mutex = 0`, and the other 31 threads loops forever.

A potential solution is to make a local copy of the shared resource in question, let 32 threads modify the copy, and then pick one thread to 'push' the change back to the shared resource. A `__shared__` variable is ideal in this situation: it will be shared by the threads belonging to the same block but not other blocks. We can use `__syncthreads()` to fine-control the access of this variable by the member threads.

[1] [CUDA Best Practices Guide - Branching and Divergence](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#branching-and-divergence)

> Avoid different execution paths within the same warp.
>
> Any flow control instruction (if, switch, do, for, while) can significantly affect the instruction throughput by causing threads of the same warp to diverge; that is, to follow different execution paths. If this happens, the different execution paths must be serialized, since all of the threads of a warp share a program counter; this increases the total number of instructions executed for this warp. When all the different execution paths have completed, the threads converge back to the same execution path.

Comment: Thanks for help. I made a little change to code in `//critical section` and got rid of that loop. Now each thread changes global resources by `atomicAdd()` and then works with its part of resource.

Comment: @Alex: could you please post your solution too. That would be really helpful.